# PHP Nesting functions OOP

Tags: php

I am using a library, and it has the following process to attach many operations to one event:

```
$action = (new EventBuilder($target))->addOperation($Operation1)->addOperation($Operation2)->addOperation($Operation3)->compile();
```

I am not sure how to dynamically add operations depending on what I need done.

Something like this

```
$action = (new EventBuilder($target));

while (some event) {
   $action = $action->addOperation($OperationX);
}

$action->compile();
```

I need to be able to dynamically add operations in while loop and when all have been added run it.

Comment: What is the `some event` condition? Are you doing something in the loop that will change the value of that expression?

Comment: How do you set `$OperationX`?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong with your code when you leave out these important details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed solution will work. The EventBuilder provides what is known as a [Fluent Interface](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html), which means that there are methods that return an instance of the builder itself, allowing you to chain calls to `addOperation` as many times as you want, then call the `compile` method to yield a result. However you are free to ignore the return value of `addOperation` as long as you have a variable containing an instance of the builder that you can eventually call `compile` on.

Take a walk with me...

```php
// Some boilerplate classes to work with
class Target
{
    private ?string $name;
    
    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class Operation
{
    private ?string $verb;
    
    public function __construct(string $verb)
    {
        $this->verb = $verb;
    }
    
    public function getVerb(): string
    {
        return $this->verb;
    }
}

class Action
{
    private ?Target $target;
    private array   $operations = [];
    
    public function __construct(Target $target, array $operations)
    {
        $this->target     = $target;
        $this->operations = $operations;
    }
    
    /**
     * Do the things
     * @return array
     */
    public function run(): array
    {
        $output = [];
        foreach ($this->operations as $currOperation)
        {
            $output[] =  $currOperation->getVerb() . ' the ' . $this->target->getName();
        }
        
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Here is a basic explanation of what your EventBuilder is doing under the covers:

```php
class EventBuilder
{
    private ?Target $target;
    private array   $operations = [];
    
    public function __construct(Target $target)
    {
        $this->target = $target;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param Operation $operation
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addOperation(Operation $operation): EventBuilder
    {
        $this->operations[] = $operation;
        
        // Fluent interface - return a reference to the instance
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function compile(): Action
    {
        return new Action($this->target, $this->operations);
    }
}
```

Let's try both techniques and prove they will produce the same result:

```php
// Mock some operations
$myOperations = [
    new Operation('Repair'),
    new Operation('Clean'),
    new Operation('Drive')
];

// Create a target
$target = new Target('Car');

/*
 * Since the EventBuilder implements a fluent interface (returns an instance of itself from addOperation),
 * we can chain the method calls together and just put a call to compile() at the end, which will return
 * an Action instance
 */
$fluentAction = (new EventBuilder($target))
                    ->addOperation($myOperations[0])
                    ->addOperation($myOperations[1])
                    ->addOperation($myOperations[2])
                    ->compile();

// Run the action
$fluentResult = $fluentAction->run();

// Traditional approach, create an instance and call the addOperation method as needed
$builder = new EventBuilder($target);

// Pass our mocked operations
while (($currAction = array_shift($myOperations)))
{
    /*
     * We can ignore the result from addOperation here, just keep calling the method
     * on the builder variable
     */
    $builder->addOperation($currAction);
}

/*
 * After we've added all of our operations, we can call compile on the builder instance to
 * generate our Action.
 */
$traditionalAction = $builder->compile();

// Run the action
$traditionalResult = $traditionalAction->run();

// Verify that the results from both techniques are identical
assert($fluentResult == $traditionalResult, 'Results from both techniques should be identical');

// Enjoy the fruits of our labor
echo json_encode($traditionalResult, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```json
[
    "Repair the Car",
    "Clean the Car",
    "Drive the Car"
]
```

Comment: Outcome of what you call traditional approach returns different result compared to first code
Here is actual code

$transaction = (new TransactionBuilder($sender))->addOperation($paymentOperation1)->build();
$transaction->sign($senderKeyPair, Network::public());

It runs perfectly

Below is code I would like to use and it fails

$transaction = new TransactionBuilder($sender);
$transaction->addOperation($paymentOperation1);
$transaction->build();
$transaction->sign($senderKeyPair, Network::public());

Error -> Call to undefined method Soneso\StellarSDK\TransactionBuilder::sign()

Comment: You're trying to call a `sign` method on the `TransactionBuilder`, which does not exist. You need to call `sign` on the `Transaction`, which is returned by the TransactionBuilder's `build` method.

$transactionBuilder = new TransactionBuilder($sender);
$transactionBuilder->addOperation($paymentOperation1);
$transaction = $transactionBuilder->build();
$transaction->sign($senderKeyPair, Network::public());

Answer (score 0):

Rob Ruchte thank you for detailed explanation, one thing I did not include was that each operation itself had ->build() call and I needed to move that to each $builder for it to work.